# How do I reduce my EBS volume capacity without losing data?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to reduce EBS volume capacity without losing data.

I would like to change the capacity from 1 TB to 200 GB.

Please provide detailed steps on how to do it.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/215395/114516

Comment: Are you talking about a root EBS volume, or a secondary EBS volume attached to an instance?

Comment: If it is not the root volume -- attach the new volume, get its identifier using **fdisk -l**, make it into a filesystem using **mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdk**, mount it **mount /dev/xvdk temp_mount/**, rsync the old to the new **rsync -a /old_mount temp_mount/**, unattach both EBS drives and re-attach the new one.

Answer (score 13):

The approach I take to decreasing an EBS root volume is as follows:

Stop (not terminate) the target instance, and detach the root EBS volume. Alternatively, you can snapshot the root volume (or use an existing snapshot) and create a new EBS volume from that. (e.g. /dev/xvda1)

Note: the volume you use from the step above will be altered - so you may want to take a snapshot if you didn't already.

```
Create a new EBS volume that is the desired size (e.g. /dev/xvdg)

Launch an instance, and attach both EBS volumes to it

Check the file system (of the original root volume): (e.g.) e2fsck -f /dev/xvda1

Maximally shrink the original root volume: (e.g. ext2/3/4) resize2fs -M -p /dev/xvda1

Copy the data over with dd:
    Choose a chunk size (I like 16MB)

    Calculate the number of chunks (using the number of blocks from the resize2fs output): blocks*4/(chunk_size_in_mb*1024) - round up a bit for safety

    Copy the data: (e.g.) dd if=/dev/xvda1 ibs=16M of=/dev/xvdg obs=16M count=80

Resize the filesystem on the new (smaller) EBS volume: (e.g.) resize2fs -p /dev/xvdg

Check the file system (of the new volume): (e.g.) e2fsck -f /dev/xvdg

Detach your new EBS root volume, and attach it to your original instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I'd like to point out there's a mistake in the penultimate line; the command is correct, but the description isn't. It actually refers to the newly resized volume, not the original volume.

Comment: Is the number of chunks the count=80 in the dd line?

Comment: And is the resize of the new FS really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from ezhilrean is OK, but there is an easier way.

Let's say you have an instance with your /var partition on /dev/sdf1 and you want to reduce this from 300GB to 200GB (presuming that there is < 200GB of data on /var)

Create a new volume in the same AZ as the original volume
Attach it to the instance as /dev/sdg
Login to instance with root permissions

```
fdisk /dev/sdg
n (for New)
p (for Primary)
Accept defaults for other fdisk options
w (for Write)
```

fdisk will then exit. You now need to make a file system on the new partition

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdg1 (presuming that ext4 was used on existing partition)
```

Next, mount you new partition at a temporary mount point

```
mkdir /new
mount /dev/sdg1 /new
```

Now, copy your data

cd /var
   cp -ax * /new/

Update your /etc/fstab to use the new partition for /var

```
/dev/sdg1   /var        ext4    defaults        0   0
```

Reboot

```
init 6
```

If you need your /var partition to have identifier /dev/sdf1, you can stop the instance, detach both EBS volumes, and re-attach the new smaller one as /dev/sdf **Remember to change /etc/fstab before you do this**

Comment: We need to attach the volume to other instance then we need to reduce it and attach it again.